# using Elasticsearch file realm for authentication instead of using roles and users APIs

Tags: elasticsearch, authentication, elk

As mentioned in the official documentation of Elasticsearch, using `file realm` to define all roles in Elasticsearch is not a preferred approach:

```
"Please note however, that the roles.yml file is provided as a minimal administrative function and is not intended to cover and be used to define roles for all use cases."
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/defining-roles.html

What is the reason? can anyone argue pros and cons of using Elasticsearch `file realm` for all roles and users instead of using its `native realm` (roles and users APIs)?

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

It depends on ones use case.
File realm can be a perfectly sound way to create your users.

BUT it has some pitfalls, such as:

- Not centralized, the file has to be replicated over every nodes in the cluster.
- Hard to update, the changes has to be replicated to every node before taking effect.
- ELastic snapshot mecanism does not cover files.

I am sure you could find Pro / Cons.
But those are some I could think of.